# Display thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory using Javascript only - Base64 encoding issue

Tags: javascript, active-directory, base64

Here's what I'm trying to do:
From an html page using only Javascript I'm trying to query the Active Directory and retrieve some user's attributes.
Which I succeded to do (thanks to some helpful code found around that I just cleaned up a bit).
I can for example display on my html page the "displayName" of the user I provided the "samAccountName" in my code, which is great.

But I also wanted to display the "thumbnailPhoto" and here I'm getting some issues...
I know that the AD provide the "thumbnailPhoto" as a byte array and that I should be able to display it in a  tag as follow:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64," />
```

including base64 encoded byte array at the end of the src attribute.

But I cannot manage to encode it at all.
I tried to use the following library for base64 encoding:
https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js

But was unsuccesful, it's acting like nothing is returned for that AD attribute, but the photo is really there I can see it over Outlook or Lync.
Also when I directly put that returned value in the console I can see some weird charaters so I guess there's something but not sure how it should be handled.

Tried a typeof to find out what the variable type is but it's returning "undefined".

I'm adding here the code I use:

```
var ADConnection = new ActiveXObject( "ADODB.connection" );
var ADCommand = new ActiveXObject( "ADODB.Command" );
ADConnection.Open( "Data Source=Active Directory Provider;Provider=ADsDSOObject" );
ADCommand.ActiveConnection = ADConnection;

var ou = "DC=XX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXX";
var where = "objectCategory = 'user' AND objectClass='user' AND samaccountname='XXXXXXXX'";
var orderby = "samaccountname ASC";
var fields = "displayName,thumbnailPhoto";
var queryType = fields.match( /,(memberof|member),/ig ) ? "LDAP" : "GC";
var path = queryType + "://" + ou;

ADCommand.CommandText = "select '" + fields + "' from '" + path + "' WHERE " + where + " ORDER BY " + orderby;

var recordSet = ADCommand.Execute;
fields = fields.split( "," );
var data = [];
while(!recordSet.EOF)
{
    var rowResult = { "length" : fields.length };
    var i = fields.length;

    while(i--)
    {
        var fieldName = fields[i];

        if(fieldName == "directReports" && recordSet.Fields(fieldName).value != null)
        {
            rowResult[fieldName] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rowResult[fieldName] = recordSet.Fields(fieldName).value;
        }
    }
    data.push(rowResult);
    recordSet.MoveNext;
}
recordSet.Close();

console.log(rowResult["displayName"]);
console.log(rowResult["thumbnailPhoto"]);
```

(I replaced db information by Xs)

(There's only one entry returned that's why I'm using the rowResult in the console instead of data)

And here's what the console returns:

> LOG: Lastname, Firstname
>
> LOG: က䙊䙉Āā怀怀

(same here Lastname & Firstname returned are the correct value expected)

This is all running on IE9 and unfortunetly have to make this compatible with IE9 :/

Summary:

- I need to find a solution in Javascript only
- I know it should be returning a byte array and I need to base64 encode it, but all my attempts failed and I'm a bit clueless on the reason why
- I'm not sure if the picture is getting returned at all here, the thing in the console seems pretty small... or if I'm nothing doing the encoding correctly

If someone could help me out with this it would be awesome, I'm struggling with this for so long now :/

Thanks!